# Cout to parent-terminal after a forked pseudo-terminal

Tags: c++, linux, pty

First I'll show you up some little pseudo code:

```
cpid = forkpty (&compipe, NULL, NULL, NULL);

//yes i have some error handling here, but its not important yet

if (cpid == 0) //child process
{
    //here are some pipes closed,
    //and the forked child will exec(ute) third party process
}

else //parent process
{
    //here are just closing some other pipe ends,
    //and settings up some fcntl flags like O_NONBLOCK

    if (string (execResult) == "fail")
    {
        //HERE ARE THE PROBLEM!!
        //This debug message will print to the pseudo-terminal (i think)
        //because it is not visible in "main"-terminal / console
        gui -> appendDbg (Output::EROR, "Could not execute FOO");
        printDbg (EROR, "Could not execute FOO");
    }

    else
    {
        //But I don't understand why this debug message prints to
        //the "main"-terminal where the application was started from
        printDbg (INFO, "Starting child process: 'FOO' with PID: " +to_string (cpid));
        printChildsOut();
    }
}
```

Ok, my problem is described inside the if-else part where the exec(ution)Result will be checked.

The thing is I can not see my debug message called 'EROR..."', but i can see the info debug message called 'INFO...' in my "main"-terminal where the application was started from.

By the way, the function 'printDbg' is developed by myself and it just prints messages via 'cout'.

Comment: The first possibility that springs to mind is that `string(execResult) != "fail"`.

Comment: Sorry forget to say that execResult is not initialized, but if the execution will not work it will be initialized with "fail". It is an char[] array.

Comment: You haven't given us enough to reproduce the error, but you can *simplify* and improve the diagnostics. If `printDbg` just wraps `cout`, then remove it and use `cout`. At the top of the "parent" block, print `execResult`; if it is not "fail", then you have your answer, and if it *is* "fail" then we can try some other things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already did that (use direct cout and print execResult). The problem is i can see the debug message on my GUI (gui -> appendDbg() WORKS). It just does not print the "printDbg" message to console from within the "if exec == fail" part.

Comment: OH MY GOD, found my mistake! The debug message was not a normal cout, it was an cerr and i started my application quiet with 2> /dev/null. Embarrassing, but thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Chalk one up for the power of simplify!